# JSF Primefaces Validation

Tags: validation, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, client-side

I have a primefaces form which uses validation:

```
<p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{addressBean.copyBillingAddress}" required="true"
    validator="#{addressBean.validateCheckbox}"
    validatorMessage="We only delivery to UK addresses. Please amend billing address or enter separate delivery address.">
    <p:ajax update="@form" />
</p:selectBooleanCheckbox>


<p:commandButton value="Continue" update="@form"
    action="#{addressBean.saveAddress}"/>
```

The copy billing address checkbox is only allowed to be selected if the delivery country is UK.
A user somehow managed to bypass this and set the delivery country as the Ukraine and still select the checkbox.

Is this validation only on the client side and a malicious user managed to bypass this check?

Comment: Only thing I can say is that validation is performed for sure only in the server side, after the form is submitted. In the end it is executing the code in the bean, and that can only be done in the server side.

Comment: Can you paste the whole xhtml (including the component for the address) and the bean code?

Comment: Please post an SSCCE. I suspect that your validator is simply broken. The only mistake/misconception which I can see in the code posted so far is that `required="true"` has totally no effect on checkboxes. Form submit can complete without checking the checkbox. But that depends of course further on the validator.

Comment: Actually the other possibility is they hacked the select box to enter a value which isnt available. Is this possible?

Comment: @DD., it shouldn't be possible to hack the select box: That's one of the functions of a converter, vis-a-vis the validations phase. If a value that doesn't exist in the list is supplied with a selectOneMenu, `Validation Error: value not valid` should be shown. Show your validator here, that should be the first suspect.